# Video is no working in safari(from Windows) but working in Mozilla and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, safari

I am working in [this](http://joychristianacademy.com/) site. The video in the home page is working fine in mozilla , google chrome and safari in mac but not working in safari in windows. the code I am using is ,

Joy Christian Academy

Click here to play

```
<div class="popmain_video" style="display: none;">
<span class="button b-close">X</span>
<video id="embed_container" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" poster="http://joychristianacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/slider1.png" preload="" controls="controls" width="80%" height="360">
<source src="http://joychristianacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Jo(H.264).mov">
<source src="http://joychristianacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/409838752.mp4">
</video>
```

Please help me to find a solution.
Thanks

Comment: after ver.5 safari stopped with win version. and that win version doesn't support many css3 so it's not strange for html5, too. try to find about html5 `video` browser support on w3school or something like that sites.

Answer (score 0):

Safari for Windows doesn't officially support HTML 5.0 or above.
This might be helpful to you,
https://superuser.com/questions/870133/html5-video-tag-not-supported-in-safari-5-1-on-windows-7